# Android SDK Update (revision 18) causes NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, revision

Slowly but surely I hat to update the android SDK…

Today I update the SDK to revision 18 and my project (before the update perfectly working) throws a NullPointer Exception even I just start it up from eclipse. I’m using eclipse with the android ADT and also update this part after update the SDK. I also tried “Fix Project Properties” with no result.

In the meanwhile my project is quit big so for the start I just post the LogCat messages, if someone need more just say it, I will post it. But I’m really disappointed that every time I update the SDK my project throws some new, mysterious errors (run into the external lib problem with revision 17…).

Hope someone can help me out! I don’t think it’s a problem with the code anyway. Its something they changed somewhere I don’t know :/

**[Update]**

I get some extra time to debug the code. The problem occurs in the construtor. It look like this (suprise, suprise):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) 
{   /// Einstiegspunkt der Android App
    super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);       
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    LoadSharedPreferences();
}
```

The exception throws after the activity tries to go to the LoadSharedPrefrerences method...

**[Update: Code around line 49]**

```
...
SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences(_saveUserDataRef, MODE_PRIVATE);
String tmpUsername = data.getString("username", null);
String tmpPassword = data.getString("password", null);
username.setText(tmpUsername);
password.setText(tmpPassword);
...
```

This snippet save the username and password if you want the app to remeber these data for you. So you dont need to write it everytime you log on.

LogCat:

```
04-12 12:09:47.615: D/dalvikvm(1094): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 47K, 48% free 2835K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 78ms
04-12 12:09:47.686: I/[POST_RESELECT](1094): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@401462d0,-1,0,-1,0)
04-12 12:09:47.686: I/[POST_RESELECT](1094): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4011b730,-1,0,-1,0)
04-12 12:09:47.696: I/[POST_RESELECT](1094): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@401462d0,-1,0,-1,0)
04-12 12:09:47.696: I/[POST_RESELECT](1094): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4011b730,-1,0,-1,0)
04-12 12:09:47.696: I/[POST_RESELECT](1094): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@401462d0,-1,0,-1,0)
04-12 12:09:47.696: I/[POST_RESELECT](1094): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4011b730,-1,0,-1,0)
04-12 12:09:47.696: I/[POST_RESELECT](1094): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@401462d0,-1,0,-1,0)
04-12 12:09:47.696: I/[POST_RESELECT](1094): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4011b730,-1,0,-1,0)
04-12 12:09:47.716: I/[POST_RESELECT](1094): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@401462d0,-1,0,-1,0)
04-12 12:09:47.716: I/[POST_RESELECT](1094): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4011b730,-1,0,-1,0)
04-12 12:09:47.716: I/[POST_RESELECT](1094): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@401462d0,-1,0,-1,0)
04-12 12:09:47.716: I/[POST_RESELECT](1094): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4011b730,-1,0,-1,0)
04-12 12:09:47.716: D/AndroidRuntime(1094): Shutting down VM
04-12 12:09:47.716: W/dalvikvm(1094): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400205a0)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.tzm.seanwesenheitsliste/de.tzm.seanwesenheitsliste.SEAnwesenheitslisteMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at de.tzm.seanwesenheitsliste.SEAnwesenheitslisteMainActivity.LoadSharedPreferences(SEAnwesenheitslisteMainActivity.java:49)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at de.tzm.seanwesenheitsliste.SEAnwesenheitslisteMainActivity.onCreate(SEAnwesenheitslisteMainActivity.java:32)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
04-12 12:09:47.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you please post the code around here: SEAnwesenheitslisteMainActivity.java:49

Comment: It's a very big activity with around 10 pages of code, interested in something special? Like somewhere around an intent or something like this?

Comment: Well, it looks like line 49 in SEAnwesenheitslisteMainActivity.java is causing the problem. Can you indicate what class your code snippet is from and show the line numbers?

Comment: I'm going to start answering as an answer that I can edit rather than lots of comments. Then you can also mark the question answered when it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell from your post which line is line 49, but my guess is:

either: `data` is `null` after `getSharedPreferences(_saveUserDataRef, MODE_PRIVATE);`

or: one of `tmpUsername` or `tmpPassword` is `null` after trying to get them from `data`.

Can you try find out if that's the case? If so, you'll know where to look next to solve the problem.

Comment: Sure, after installing the app both variables are not filled and both take the default vale, here defined as `null`. But before revision 18 (I really test it!) the `EditText` just leaves blank (as I expected). Now this behaviour throws an exception. 

I can not understand why this error occurs now and not from the beginng… but the problem is solved now…

Comment: I forgot: Replace `null` with an empty string `""` solves the problem, thank you for your time! Write this as answer i will accept it.

Comment: cool, thanks. I'm glad it's fixed. You can accept this as the answer by clicking the tick to the left of the Answer